# texshade: Error ! Paragraph ended before \inf@@get was complete

Tags: pdftex, errors, packages

I am trying to get multiple alignments to render with texshade but it seems that there is a problem with the package. When trying to use a file the following is output to the console:

> Runaway argument?
> ! Paragraph ended before \inf@@get was complete.
>
> \par
> l.13 \begin{texshade}{Result.fasta_aln`enter code here`}
> ?

I have tried versions 1.25 and 1.26 of texshade with no luck in either MSF or fasta_aln files.
A minimal working tex example here:

```
    \documentclass[
]{article}

\usepackage{texshade}

\begin{document}

\begin{texshade}{Result.fasta_aln}
\hideconsensus
\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

And the contents of Result.fasta_aln are:

```
>1aboA
NL-FVAL---YDFVASGDNTLSITKGEKLR-------VLGYNH-------NGEWCE--AQTKNGQGWVPSNYITPV-N--
---
>1ycsB
KGVIYAL---WDYEPQNDDELPMKEGDCMT-------IIHREDED-----EIEWWW--ARLNDKEGYVPRNLLGLY----
--P
>1pht
GYQYRAL---YDYKKEREEDIDLHLGDILTVNKGSLVALGFSDGQEARPEEIGWLNGYNETTGERGDFPGTYVEYIGRKK
ISP
>1vie
DR-----------VRKK--SGAAWQGQIVGWYCTNLTPEGYAVESEAHPGSV-------------QIYPVAALERI----
--N
>1ihvA
NF-RVYYRDSRDPVWKGPAK-LLWKGEGAV-------VIQDNS-------DIK-------------VVPRRKAKIIRD--
---
```

Digging through the .sty file one can find \inf@@get but I don't know why it is failing (one would assume some sort of escape character interaction?). Interestingly enough trying this same thing on my desktop running Linux results in no problem.

Here is the definition contained within the .sty file:

```
\def\inf@@get#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6@{%
   \def\first@{#1}
   \def\second@{#2}
   \def\third@{#3}
   \xdef\fourth@{#4 @}
   \expandafter\check@letter\fourth@
   \ifnumber
      \def\fourth@{#4}
   \else
      \xdef\fourth@{#5 @}
      \expandafter\check@letter\fourth@
      \ifnumber
         \def\fourth@{#5}
      \else
         \def\fourth@{99999999}
      \fi
   \fi
   \def\fifth@{#5}
   \def\last@{#6}}
```

And the command is utilized here:

```
\expandafter\inf@@get\msfline
```

Trying on Overleaf (using) results in the same error with corrupted output attached as an image. An additional error pops up as well:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\msfline ->\par &
                      & & & @
    l.24 {result.fasta_aln}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You state that it works on a Linux desktop, but you don't say where it does not work (a Windows desktop? Overleaf? A Linux server?)

Comment: @Marijn My bad, I am trying it on a windows desktop (also tried it on a laptop). Trying it on overleaf seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: @J823 Did you resolve the issue? I'm seeing the same behaviour with my installation of TexLive 2021 with texshade 1.2.6.

Comment: @CatThatKilledCuriosity Unfortunately, no. It does work on Linux so I just did my work on my archlinux install. Might be a good idea to report this issue to the dev(s) of TexShade and see if they can fix it. I think I'll do that this weekend.

Comment: Which type of TeX engine you used? i(.e., `LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf` or `PDFLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX,` etc)

Comment: @MadyYuvi PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX. If one tests this MWE in Overleaf this issue will arise in both with the 2021 TeX Live version of either but not in the 2020 version of either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out someone posted this solution on the comments of the Texshade package at CTAN:

[Package texshade at CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texshade)

> Fix for people who are getting errors while using TeXshade v1.26:
>
> 1. Locate the file texshade.sty on your system. This may vary based on how you installed LaTeX.
> 2. Find the line below (should be line 156 in v1.26 released on 2021/04/01):
>    \xdef\par@{\expandafter\string\par}
> 3. Replace it with these two lines:
>    \xdef\par@{\par}
>    \xdef\par@{\expandafter\string\par@}
>
> Should work now.

After applying this, I also noticed that if you used the package Textopo at the same time, it raises more errors
*Edit: at the CTAN textopo page, there is a similar fix fir this other situation. [Textopo at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/textopo)*

Otherwise it works fine.